# group by query with sum all value

Tags: sql, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have Product table in SQL Like this:

```
productID   Type               Amount
1046          1                 4  
1046          1                 5  
1046          2                 10          
1047          1                 5           
1047          2                 3
```

How to make a query, output like this:

```
productID   Type          TotalTypeAmount    TotalPerProductID
1046          1                9                  19
1046          2                10                 19
1047          1                 5                  8
1047          2                 3                  8
```

Comment: TotalAllType is badly named. It should be TotalPerProductID, no?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes exactly!

Comment: for 1046 and 1047 have type 1 & 2 but why only showing for 1046

Comment: This can be solved by scanning the table only once (no join) - see my posted example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this way also we can do

```
   Select 
T.productID,
T.Type,
T.Tamount,
TT.FAmount
     from (
select 
        productID, 
        Type, 
        SUM(Amount)Tamount 
from 
    Product
GROUP BY  productID, Type
)T
INNER JOIN (
select 
    productID,
    SUM(Amount)FAmount 
from 
    Product
GROUP BY  productID
)TT
ON T.productID = TT.productID
```

Comment: Using a windowing function on the grouped query would have been nicer

Answer (score 13):

A more compact/professional way, should be faster too because it doesn't require join:

```
SELECT 
  productID,
  Type,
  SUM(Amount) AS TotalTypeAmount,
  SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY productID) as TotalPerProduct
FROM 
  Product
GROUP BY 
  productID,Type
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca308/4

---

`SUM(amount)` is the SUM of amount per `productid,type` i.e. the SUM you would get if you just did the GROUP BY so you'll have multiple different sums per `productid` because they're broken down into `type` subgroups. `SUM(SUM(amount)) PARTITION BY(productid)` is "the sum of sum_per_productid_and_type grouped by productid only"

Suppose we had the simpler query:

```
SELECT 
  productID,
  Type,
  SUM(Amount) AS TotalTypeAmount
FROM 
  Product
GROUP BY 
  productID,Type
```

This might produce results like:

```
id1, type1, 100
id1, type2, 200
id2, type1, 300
id2, type2, 400
```

We can see that the total for all `id1` would be `300`, and the total for all id2 would be `700`. We can introduce a window function to sum all the data by productid only, and it would produce results where the sum repeats, rather than causing the number of rows to shrink, i.e.:

```
id1, type1, 100, 300
id1, type2, 200, 300
id2, type1, 300, 700
id2, type2, 400, 700
```

This is because window functions do a grouping/summing but then apply the result to every row.

It is important to understand that a window operation is performed AFTER the grouping and summing is done, but BEFORE we have given the columns any aliases in the SELECT. If the column names HAD been assigned before the window function was run then we could have said `SUM(TotalTypeAmount)` instead of `SUM(SUM(Amount))`:

```
SELECT 
  productID,
  Type,
  SUM(Amount) AS TotalTypeAmount,
  SUM(TotalTypeAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY productID) as TotalPerProduct
FROM 
  Product
GROUP BY 
  productID,Type
```

But this is a syntax error, because we can't refer to TotalTypeAmount in the same SELECT as we define it. We could make this happen by using a subquery though:

```
SELECT
  x.productID,
  x.Type,
  x.TotalTypeAmount, --here we use it after it has been defined in the subquery
  SUM(x.TotalTypeAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY x.productID) as TotalPerProduct
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    productID,
    Type,
    SUM(Amount) AS TotalTypeAmount --here we define it
  FROM 
    Product
  GROUP BY 
    productID,Type
) x
```

But it's more complex than it needs to be.

In essence, though it looks weird, we just need to remember that when we see:

```
SUM(sum(…)) OVER(PARTITION BY …)
…
group by …
```

- The inner `sum(amount)` in lowercase is "the sum that is done by the GROUP BY", and
- The outer `SUM(…) OVER(…)` in uppercase is "the sum that is done by the window function"

We had to repeat ourselves and say `SUM(SUM(amount))` because at the time the window function was being run, the sum done by the group by (i.e. the thing we wanted to total up) didn't have its own name - it was just called `SUM(amount)`

Comment: very good answer. Why do you need the sum(sum())? I noticed it does not work without that.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using SQL Server or Postgres the below should work:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 
productID,
SUM(Amount) AS TotalAllType
FROM Product
GROUP BY productID
)

SELECT 
productID,
Type,
SUM(Amount) AS TotalTypeAmount
,TotalAllType
FROM Product AS P
LEFT JOIN CTE ON CTE.productID=P.productID
GROUP BY productID,Type, TotalAllType;
```